How to dispaly selection of empty lines in QML TextArea?
I'm using TextArea, but there is some trouble with selection. Empty lines visually not selected. How to dispaly selection of empty lines in QML TextArea?
this is my view

this is what i want

TextArea {
   selectByMouse: true
   selectionColor: "grey"
   wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
   color: "black"
   textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
   implicitHeight: 200
}


What you are seeking for is that the end-of-line characters are also shown as transparent characters which then get marked like regular characters in the selection. It is nigh impossible to achieve with current QML. It is a design decision in how the text is displayed in the editor and it is not configurable in Qt's text editor. There is a cursor delegate which can be done to change the appearance of the cursor, but I don't see that for the selection.

It's very strange situation. Every and every editors (for exaple: GMail web, KMail, LibreOffice, WhatsApp, Telegram e.t.c) they are all have a selection of \n or <br>simbols. But only QtQuick have a null selection. I don't understand why Qt maked this.

That seems odd indeed. Text based widgets in QtWidgets (QTextEdit, but also QGraphicsTextItem) always show selections for empty lines too. I don't know if it may count but can you check whether you're using native rendering or not, and eventually try to switch it?

I'm tryed to use renderType: Text.NativeRendering nothing changes.

A "trick" you can do is use two TextArea. The primary TextArea is for the user editing including interaction with the mouse. The secondary TextArea is for rendering the selection.
With the secondary TextArea you can modify the RichText format to add a whitespace &nbsp;.
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
    TextArea {
        id: shadow
        selectionColor: "lightblue"
        wrapMode: ta.wrapMode
        width: ta.width
        textFormat: chkDebug.checked ? TextEdit.PlainText : ta.textFormat
        y: chkDebug.checked ? 200 : 0
    }

    TextArea {
        id: ta
        selectByMouse: true
        selectionColor: chkDebug.checked ? "orange" : "transparent"
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        color: "black"
        textFormat: TextEdit.RichText
        width: parent.width
        implicitHeight: 200
        text: "123<br/>\n<br />\n123<br />\n<br />\nABC<br />\n"
        onTextChanged: Qt.callLater(updateShadow)
        onSelectionStartChanged: Qt.callLater(updateShadow)
        onSelectionEndChanged: Qt.callLater(updateShadow)
        Component.onCompleted: select(0, 10)
    }
    
    function updateShadow() {
        shadow.text = ta.text.replace(/(<br \/>|<\/p>)/g, lf => "&nbsp;" + lf)
        if (chkDebug.checked) return;
        let r1 = ta.positionToRectangle(ta.selectionStart);
        let r2 = ta.positionToRectangle(ta.selectionEnd);
        let s = shadow.positionAt(r1.x + r1.width / 2, r1.y + r2.height / 2);
        let e = shadow.positionAt(r2.x + r2.width / 2, r2.y + r2.height / 2);
        shadow.select(s, e);
    }

    footer: CheckBox {
        id: chkDebug; text: "Debug"
        onToggled: Qt.callLater(updateShadow)
    }
}

You can Try it Online!

It's looks like a workaround, but I guess there's no another way, Thx a lot

NOTE: we need to consider -qt-paragraph-type:empty; in , to avoid hiding content.
